# Правильно ли составлено? Можно учреждать фестивали?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Органам местного самоуправления содействовать: учреждению Межрегионального фестиваля народных художественных промыслов Поволжья; проведению научно-практической конференции по теме...  и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, если речь идёт не об однократном мероприятии, а о создании постоянно действующей организации (со своим фондом, штатом, уставом), которая будет периодически проводить названный фестиваль. Примеров таких фестивалей в мире много (Isle of Wight, Bonnaroo, Lollapalooza, Cambridge Folk, Glastonbury...). Вместо точки с запятой здесь достаточно просто запятой.